# Object is black when in textured view with GLSL shading Blender render

Tags: texturing, normal-map

I created a face model, and am trying to get the normal map onto it. I switched to Blender Render, baked the Normals, and saved the image. I went into GLSL shading, and added a new texture on the model. I switched to texture view and it's black.
[image]

In solid view, it's the default white, and when the Texture Solid is checked in Solid view, it adds the blue texture, which is not supposed to happen. 
I think it's supposed to look like this, when adding the normal map.

[image]

The tutorial I'm following can be found here for more information.
https://youtu.be/H57IDJNeD3U?t=1m46s

How do I get it to show like the second image with the normal map without the black texture?

Comment: please attach the .blend via http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Don't you need add a source light?. As i see in the outliner you don't have a lamp, maybe it's what you need.

Comment: Add some light there is no light

Comment: Thank you very much! I never knew you needed a light source in this setup.